# .htaccess rewrite rules for PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have structure php url like:

```
example.com/category.php?cat=graphics-and-design
```

and I want to clean the url via a .htaccess rewrite rule to:

```
example.com/category/graphics-and-design
```

I tried the following code but still doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\/(.*)$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please show the complete contents of your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want problems later with other rules, for example not being able to match `example.com/project/foobar` without it going to `category.php?cat=foobar`

Then I suggest you match the category as well:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

If you still want to go down that route (pun intended), the problem is its passing the `$1`'st match:

```
example.com/category.php?cat=category
```

So instead pass match `$2`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/(.*)$ category.php?cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried both none work for me. It generated 500 error.

Comment: You need to use `RewriteEngine On` and rewrite needs to be enabled.

Comment: Your need to check your apache error logs then, as i've tested both rules just to make sure, and no 500's